# Padding negative numbers with 0 using .format()

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to format negative numbers with padded 0's.

The problem is that I'm getting the 0's added to the left side of the negative sign.

```
dac = -12
dac2 = 411
print('{:>07d}, {:>07d}'.format(dac, dac2))
```

results in:
`>>> 0000-12, 0000411`

what I want is:
`>>> -000012, 0000411`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the `>` alignment specifier. That aligns the number *including the sign*, in the right-hand-part of the column, and the remainder is padded with zeros.

Without `>`, padding is applied between the sign and the number:

```
>>> print('{:07d}, {:07d}'.format(dac, dac2))
-000012, 0000411
```

The default for 0-padded numbers is the `=` alignment, so you can also make that explicit:

```
>>> print('{:=07d}, {:=07d}'.format(dac, dac2))
-000012, 0000411
```

From the [*Format Specification Mini-Language* section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

> `'='`
>   Forces the padding to be placed after the sign (if any) but before the digits. This is used for printing fields in the form ‘+000000120’. This alignment option is only valid for numeric types. It becomes the default when ‘0’ immediately precedes the field width.

and further down

> When no explicit alignment is given, preceding the width field by a zero (`'0'`) character enables sign-aware zero-padding for numeric types. This is equivalent to a fill character of `'0'` with an alignment type of `'='`.